# Count one-to-many using left join gives wrong count on source table

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

I have two tables `user_results` and `user_shares`

`user_results` has:

```
id - pk
platform - string
country - string
created_at - timestamp
```

`user_shares` has:

```
id - pk
user_result_id - integer
created_at - timestamp
```

This is my query:

```
select 
    count(user_results.id) as results,
    count(user_shares.id) as shares,
    user_results.platform as platform 
from
    user_results
left join 
    user_shares on user_results.id = user_shares.user_result_id 
group by 
    platform
```

Here's a sql fiddle with the schema and problematic query:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/739a3/2

Now, as you can see on the fiddle I have only 1 result per platform but the `results` count shows (i guess) the "results count without share + shares count"

What do I do wrong?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: he has problem with first: `results` column

Comment: I think it should be 1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need is to count `distinct user_results.id`, because joined table duplicates its rows:

```
select 
  count(distinct user_results.id) as results,
  count(user_shares.id) as shares,
  user_results.platform as platform 
from
  user_results
left join 
  user_shares on user_results.id = user_shares.user_result_id 
group by 
  platform
```

Comment: Damn it! how did I forget that. Thank you George!